# Google Cloud Storage as file storage for multiple users

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I need the following:-
I want to give access to Google Cloud Storage for multiple users.

I will create a Google project and will do the following:
I want each of them to have their-

1. Regional storage bucket: with 5-25 GB/user space allocation based on their location. They will store and use their data as files.
2. Coldline storage bucket: Each user can store approximately 1TB of archival data/files over here.

I need to provide the users to have an easy uploading environment (like Google Drive).

I want to sent storage usage alerts, if they runs out of space.

Please suggest me or connect me to the right person for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simply to set up a NAS Server (google cloud based) and tag it to the aforementioned storage.